# Strtolower function not working on my page

Tags: php, forms

Strtolower function is not working, when i print_r i get exactly what i input.
Cannot realize what's going on.

```
 $ulogus = strtolower($_POST['username']);
 $ulogpa = strtolower($_POST['password']);
 $ulogus = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
 $plogpa = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

I have also tried to use mb_strtolower()

Input:

```
 <label>Username</label>
 <input name="username" type="text" class="textfields" />
 </div>
 <div class="formblock">
 <label>Password</label><input name="password" type="password" class="textfields"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you give an example of your input ?

Comment: Clearly strtolower() is broken, and you're the first person among millions of php developers ever to notice this - now perhaps fix your code.

Comment: DO not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: And __STOP__ using the MySQL library.... use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements.... learn good habits, not bad ones

Comment: @im7xs - Recommending that you use good practises rather than bad is not a stupid comment - it's meant in good faith, to help make you a better developer

Comment: @Mark Baker i agree but ur comment wasn't usefull, ofc my strtolower() was broken, i noticed it alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are overwriting the variable. you must change code like  this

```
 $_POST['username'] = strtolower($_POST['username']);
 $_POST['password'] = strtolower($_POST['password']);
 $ulogus = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
 $plogpa = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

Comment: Thank you, stupid error.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$ulogus = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['username']));
$plogpa = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['password']));
```

You're overwriting `$ulogus`.

Answer (score 3):

you keep pulling the same data from the same place, replacing the earlier tolower()

```
$ulogus = strtolower($_POST['username']);
$ulogus = mysql_real_escape_string($ulogus);
                                   ^^^^^^^
```